# CSS: space between padding and border

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to remove some white space around an :after section, but for some reason there is always a tiny bit of white space between the red border and the part saying "copy" on the top, bottom, and right parts.

```css
.c-button--copy:after {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ed1a3b;
    content: "copy";
    display: flex;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-transform: none;
}
*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.c-button {
    border-radius: 50rem;
    margin: 8px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 8px 32px;
    border-width: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.c-button--copy {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 4px solid #ed1a3b;
    padding-right: 88px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="btn c-button c-button--white c-button--copy">
            Hello
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you have any questions please let me know

Comment: sorry. i cannot reproduce this behaviour. Which browser are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: Which version ?

Comment: Version 87.0.4280.141

Comment: Weird, thats a fairly new browser that should support everything ...

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `overflow:hidden` from your `a` add border radius to the `:after` element (just top-right and bottom-right) amd move it slightly to the right:  `right:-2px;`

```css
.c-button--copy:after {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ed1a3b;
    content: "copy";
    display: flex;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -2px;
    text-transform: none;
    border-top-right-radius:50rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50rem;
    
}
*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.c-button {
    border-radius: 50rem;
    margin: 8px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 8px 32px;
    border-width: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.c-button--copy {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 4px solid #ed1a3b;
    padding-right: 88px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="btn c-button c-button--white c-button--copy">
            Hello
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```